# Replacing <br> in a textbox

Tags: c#, asp.net, textbox, datalist

I have a textbox in a Datalist with text that I get from a Database. There are alot of `<br>` in that text and I want linebreaks instead of `<br>`, This is what it looks like:

```
((TextBox)(EditProductList.Items[0].FindControl("txtEditDescription"))).Text.Replace("<br>", "\r\n");
```

---

```
 <asp:DataList ID="EditProductList" runat="server">
   <ItemTemplate>
     <asp:TextBox ID="txtEditDescription" runat="server" TextMode="MultiLine" Height="350px"
                            Width="350px" Text='<%#Eval("Description") %>'></asp:TextBox>
  </ItemTemplate>
</asp:DataList>
```

I get the text but I get the `<br>` as well.

Comment: You know .Replace returns a string, it doesn't operate on whats inside, right?

Comment: Just an FYI: If you're working with primarily plain text, but using `<br>` instead of line breaks because you're displaying on the web, the best method is to store plain text with line breaks, and translate those to `<br>` as you build your markup. That way you can adapt to new display modes (like moving from `<br>` to `<br />` as you go from html4 to xhtml and then back to `<br>` for html5!)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You actually have to assign the string returned by `Replace()` to the `Text` property again.

```
var textBox = (TextBox)(EditProductList.Items[0].FindControl("txtEditDescription"));
textBox.Text = textBox.Text.Replace("<br>", "\r\n");
```

Comment: After finding the control make sure that TextBox is Not null then only Replace the text, else exception will get fired.

Comment: @Maxymus excellent commentary. Just bear in mind that we don't want to overload the new dev with unrelated advice directly. But an excellent bit of commentary.

Answer (score 1):

Try this instead (but it should be refactored):

Using your original code:

```
((TextBox)(EditProductList.Items[0].FindControl("txtEditDescription"))).Text = 
          ((TextBox)(EditProductList.Items[0].FindControl("txtEditDescription"))).Text.Replace("<br>", "\r\n");
```

And refactor it like this:

```
TextBox textBox = ((TextBox)(EditProductList.Items[0].FindControl("txtEditDescription")));
textbox.Text = textBox.Text.Replace("<br>", "\r\n");
```

Notice that in the refactoring I'm replacing the lookup with a reference to the already found control.

The reason why we do it like this is that the .Replace function doesn't mutate the object in question, it returns a mutated version of the object, so to speak.

Comment: @Nicklas you can show your thanks more by clicking the checkmark and the up arrow ;) This lets others know that this solved your problem and was the answer you were looking for.